# Handle "(null)" value in Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User {get;set;}
}
```

I am calling a service that will sometimes represent empty values as "(null)", like so:

```
{"name":"(null)", "dateCreated":"(null)", "user":"(null)"}
```

What is the best way to handle this?  I've tried plugging in custom contract resolvers, but I don't want to have to do that for everything.  Is there a way I could override the tokenization, so that this could be treated as null?  Or some other extenisibility point to take advantage of?

Comment: _"What is the best way to handle this?"_ Get the service to output a proper response of `null` :)  Failing that, I'm sure there's a way to actually cope with it...

Comment: Sounds like a crappy server ;P

Comment: Sorry guys, server is not under my control.

Comment: A `string.Replace` on `"(null)"` to `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is probably to load your JSON to a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) then replace the `"(null)"` string tokens with actual null tokens:

```
        var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        foreach (var value in obj.Descendants().OfType<JValue>().Where(v => v.Type == JTokenType.String && (string)v == "(null)").ToList())
            value.Replace(JValue.CreateNull());

        var myClass = obj.ToObject<MyClass>();
```

Note that you're going to need to change your `DateTimeOffset` property to a nullable to do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTimeOffset? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could could completely remove psuedo-null-valued properties:

```
        var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        foreach (var value in obj.Descendants().OfType<JValue>().Where(v => v.Type == JTokenType.String && (string)v == "(null)").ToList())
        {
            if (value.Parent.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                value.Parent.Remove(); // Psuedo null-valued object property.  Remove the property.
            else
                value.Replace(JValue.CreateNull()); // Psuedo null-valued array entry.  Replace with null to avoid reindexing the array.
        }

        var myClass = obj.ToObject<MyClass>();
```

Comment: Perfect.  This is the solution I tried, but stumbled around too much with my unfamiliarity with `JObject`s to get working correctly.  Thanks.